# Unidentified CSS element

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm seeing a dotted white border around a  element (only in Firefox, not Chrome or Safari).

Screenshot -

[image: white border]

Any idea what it is? There are no "-moz*" css rules on the element, and I'm unable to find any property that removes it.

Comment: Any demo or can we look at your code please.

Comment: Thanks, but Punith's answer helped. Bootstrap was applying a outline to the parent element on focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove all outline in your css which look like this

```
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color; 
   outline-offset: -2px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*for FireFox*/
    input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner
    {   
        border : 0px;
    } 
/*for IE8 */
    input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="button"]:focus
    {     
        outline : none; 
    }
```

**or**

```
 #myElement { outline: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-moz-focus-inner {    
outline:0 none !important;
}
```